# Common implementaion for scoped procedure

Tags: c++

I am interested in common practice/implementation of a pattern which I would call "scoped procedure". I even don't know how to name it correctly :)

The thing I am talking about is close to `boost::scoped_exit` and `boost::scoped_connection`: a class, which

- holds user-provided functor,
- shares the functor on object copying,
- have a counter to count all objects sharing given functor,
- calls the fuctor when the counter becomes 0.

The candidate I can think about is `boost::shared_ptr`, but it seems to me a bit awkward to store there some fake pointer.

Can you give any suggestion/best practice for this?

The case I want to apply it to is as follows. There is some registry class which stores a collection of records for associated objects of some other class. When an object is "registered" in the collection it receives a registration ID. When the object wants to unregister it just "releases the ID" (by going out of scope or calling a method similar to `boost::scoped_connection::disconnect()`). On release a user-provided procedure would be called to remove a corresponding record from the collection.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why awkward? Just create an object that calls the functor in its destructor and pack it in a shared pointer.